# What file format are these files?

Tags: import

I am trying to import tables from an unknown DBMS.  The file extensions for a table end in -nothing-, `.d` and `.k`.

Presumably there is a table file, an index file and a memo file (like FoxPro uses) but I can't work out what the database file format is.

An example table can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l40wsistkawliam/PATIENT.zip?dl=0).